# Emulator GPU Not Working

Tags: android, android-studio, opengl-es

I have tried to run the android emulator and am receiving the following message when I attempt to use my computers GPU (use host GPU):

```
/Users/User/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full - avd Nexus_5_API_22_Play
sh: file: No such file or directory
sh: grep: No such file or directory
sh: file: No such file or directory
WARNING: Cannot decide host bitness because $SHELL is not properly defined; 32  bits assumed.
emulator: ERROR: Could not load OpenGLES emulation library [lib64OpenglRender]: dlopen(lib64OpenglRender.dylib, 1): image not found
emulator: ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it.
```

I know where the file lib64OpenglRender.dylib is: /Users/User/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib64